# error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘stdin’

Tags: c, compiler-errors

tfgets.c:11:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘stdin’

```
char *fgets(char *out, int size, stdin)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue or what it even means.

Comment: That's an incorrect declaration of `fgets`.  The correct declaration is in the standard header `<stdio.h>`, so there's no reason for user code to redefine it.

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own fgets() function

Comment: Unless this is part of an actual C library implementation, you should use a name other than `fgets`. Giving your own function the same name as a standard library function causes undefined behavior. (If you're actually implementing a C library, of course `fgets` is the correct name.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring the function, add type to the third argument.

```
char *fgets(char *out, int size, FILE* in);
```

If you are calling the function, use:

```
fgets(out, size, stdin);
```

Comment: I'm calling the function with the exact same parameters you've indicated i.e. fgets(out, size, stdin);

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own version of fgets(), might this be why this is happening? (I dont think it is but I thought I should throw that out there anyways)

Comment: @Eric, your trying to implement a version of `fgets()` has nothing to do with the error. The error was caused by the missing type in the declaration.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this?